# In What Windows Library is glCreateProgramObjectARB Defined?

Tags: windows, opengl, shader

I'm trying to do some shader programming on windows. All the code I've been able to find online says you have to use wglGetProcAddress to figure out where these functions are, but i'm not sure what library to link against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben Voigt's answer is nearly correct, with two exceptions:

- All OpenGL 1.0 and 1.1 functionality is inlcuded in opengl32.lib, only 1.3 and upwards and all extension must be loaded dynamically.
- WGL guarantees that all contexts sharing the same pixel format share identical function pointers. This is an important detail, as otherwise any application using either OpenGL 3.x/4.x or multisampling would necessarily be malformed.

However, in short, forget all this blah blah. Download [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and be done in 5 minutes. It just works and you need not care about petty implementation details. Call one init function at program start, and everything is good.

Comment: +1 for recommending GLEW. This makes handling the extensions on windows easy.

Comment: skt: Do you have a reference for "same function pointer for all contexts"?  I'm under the impression that if you had two video cards from different vendors, you could get different function pointers.  In fact, not handling multiple sets of function pointers is the only advantage of GLEW I can see.  GLee "GL Easy Extensions" is superior in several other ways.  And I don't understand the part about "necessarily malformed".  After calling `wglCreateContextAttrib`, you could throw away all your existing pointers and get new ones, I think GLEW does this actually.

Comment: Sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374386%28VS.85%29.aspx  (last paragraph)  "The extension function addresses are unique for each pixel format. All rendering contexts of a given pixel format share the same extension function addresses."

Comment: skt: So are pixel formats corresponding to different video cards but identical in all attributes (color depth, etc) distinguishable somehow?

Comment: By the wording, one could assume that function pointers on different video cards are the same, but the wording is deceptive. Pixel formats with identical bitplanes will have different identifiers on different video cards, so they're not the same ones.

Answer (score 2):

You link against `opengl32.lib` to get `wglGetProcAddress`.  All the rest must be dynamically obtained via `wglGetProcAddress` after you have made a context current, since different contexts can use different implementations of the various functions.

An extension loader such as GLee or GLEW can do the function-pointer details for you, but you still need to be linking `opengl32.lib`.